# How to clear ALL retained mqtt messages from Mosquitto?

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I've seen the `mosquitto_pub -h [server] -r -n -t [XYZ]` syntax for clearing out one off messages.  My problem is the device developers have posted a lot of garbage messages.

I have a Java/Paho code base that I'd like to modify to do this automatically as needed, but I can't seem to publish a zero byte message.  I tried

```
client.publish(topic,null);
```

...but that didn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on how to delete everything, en mass?

Comment: This might help: `mosquitto_sub -t '#' --remove-retained --retained-only`. See also: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 options for this using the paho client code depending on which of the 2 `publish` methods you use.

```
MqttMessage msg = new MqttMessage(new byte[0]);
msg.setRetained(true);
client.publish(topic, msg);
```

or

```
client.publish(topic, new byte[0],0,true);
```

The other option would be to stop mosquitto and delete the persistence file and restart

Comment: Actually, first version will not work, as the message needs to be published with the retained flag set.

Comment: Deleting the persistence file turned out to be the option I really needed.

Comment: This is how I deleted the persistence file in Ubuntu 16.04:
    `sudo service mosquitto stop`
    `sudo rm /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db`
    `sudo service mosquitto start`
You can check in your **mosquitto.conf** where your **persistence_file** is located.

Comment: It is important to understand that deleting the persistence file also wipes out all queued messages and any persistent subscriptions. It is better to clear individual topics with publishing a null message in a production environment

Comment: @TobiasHolm Sovle my problem! Thanks!!

Answer (score 26):

Here is how to do it properly with a shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "cleaning " $1 " :: usage: cleanmqtt <host>"
mosquitto_sub -h $1 -t "#" -v --retained-only | while read line; do mosquitto_pub -h $1 -t "${line% *}" -r -n; done
```

Just put it in a file called somthing like

> cleanmqtt.sh

Then run

```
sh cleanmqtt.sh localhost
```

This solution is quite crude. You cant specify what to delete or anything.
You may have to abort with ctrl-c after you can assume that it has received all the messages.

Comment: Could you show how to modify the script to include username and password? When I run it, I get "Connection Refused: not authorised". Thanks.

Comment: Sure, add -u _username_ -P _password_ in the line to both the mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub

Comment: If your topic has spaces in it, you can change the command to:

`mosquitto_sub -h $1 -t "#" -v | while read line; do mosquitto_pub  -h $1 -t "${line% *}" -r -n; done`

The change is to remove the `_` after `read line` and change `$line` to `${line% *}`

Comment: Cool Robert, I changed to your suggestion

Answer (score 10):

Mosquitto client provides --remove-retained option:

```
mosquitto_sub -h $host --remove-retained -t '#' -W 1
```

Tunning -t can handle specific topics to be cleared.

Comment: This is the most efficient way, however, when using `-E` the client exits immediately after `Client X received SUBACK` i.e. after subscribing, but before receiving any messages, so actual removal doesn't happen. The only reliable way to make the client disconnect and exit that I found is using `-W 1` flag, i.e. process messages for 1 sec then exit.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have enough points to comment, running

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "cleaning " $1 " :: usage: cleanmqtt <host>"
mosquitto_sub -h $1 -t "#" -v | while read line; do mosquitto_pub -h $1 -t "${line% *}" -r -n; done
```

could cause an infinite loop due to pub/sub delays. 
Adding `--retained-only` to `mosquitto_sub` seems to remove the infinite loop.

Comment: Nice! I added it. This also solves the ctrl-c issue. There is also a --remove-retained but I can't seem to understand how that works.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
client.publish(topic, new byte[]{}, 0, true);
```

Also, you may be interested in [this script](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/client_mqtt_clear_retain.py) from Eclipse Paho Python, to clear a given topic hierarchy. You may want to implement a similar behavior in Java, but it looks like you may be looking for a one-off solution, so maybe just use the Python script :)

Comment: The python script doesnt seem to work with non-ascii topics or payloads. The shell script I just posted seems to work better.

Comment: "this script" link is now 404

Answer (score 1):

### for powershell users

had this issue on windows, so here with powershell. Mosquitto needs to be installed on the command host.

#### get retained messages

I did not want to clear all retained messages. Example, only the ones containing "octo" in it's topic. Let's see what's there:

```
mosquitto_sub.exe -h <mqtt host> -v -u <mqtt user> -P <mqtt password> -t '#' --retained-only|
Select-String octo
```

(replace mqtt host, user, password as needed)

#### delete retained messages

use the same search string here ( in this example "octo"):

```
mosquitto_sub.exe -h <mqtt host> -v -u <mqtt user> -P <mqtt password> -t '#' --retained-only|
Select-String octo |
Out-String -Stream|ForEach-Object -Process {$_.Split(" ")[0]}|
%{mosquitto_pub.exe -h <mqtt host> -u <mqtt user> -P <mqtt password> -t "$_" -r -n}
```

Again, replace all occurences of mqtt host, user, password.

Simply check again with step 1 if anything is left :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Mosquitto MQTT Broker, disable "Retained messages" using the official method, provided by Mosquitto

**First find mosquitto.conf file**

*(In my Ubuntu/EC2 instance it is stored in /etc/mosquitto directory, I assume your mosquitto.conf file path is /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf)*

Edit with your favorite text editor, mine is nano.

```
sudo nano /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

and in that file replace "persistence false" in place of "persistence true"

```
persistence false
```

Now save file *(if using nano press ctrl+o and then enter to save, ctrl+x to exit)*

now restart mosquitto using below commands

```
sudo service mosquitto stop
sudo service mosquitto start
```

**Note:** If this config path does not exist in your case, find config file using this command-

```
sudo find / -name mosquitto.conf
```

[image]

Comment: That just stops retained messages being stored, across restarts, it doesn't actually clear them (in a running broker)

Comment: Agreed, for that remove/re-create db file (manually or by such code:file_operation) which is stored in persistence_location (or in my case /var/lib/mosquitto/mosquitto.db)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to add a simple comment. The bash script is great! The edge case I ran into is one where multiple spaces exist, such as a date stamp:

```
bob/was/here/time 2021-08-31 01:52:51
```

${line% *} only removes the time while including the date with the topic. Adding a second % to ${line%% *} makes the substitution greedy, ensuring that only the topic is returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you´re on a remote computer you can do this.

```
mosquitto_sub -h HOST -t 'TOPIC' --remove-retained --retained-only -u USER -P PASSWORD
```

It works for me !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From the `mosquitto_sub` [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/mosquitto-clients/mosquitto_sub.1.en.html#OPTIONS)

> **Example 1.**  Remove all retained messages on the server, assuming we have access to do so, and then exit:
>
> ```
> mosquitto_sub -t '#' --remove-retained --retained-only
> ```

As a function:

```
clmq(){ mosquitto_sub -t '#' --remove-retained --retained-only -d -W ${4:-1} -h ${1:-localhost} -u ${2} -P ${3}; }
```

Example usage:

```
clmq myhostoripaddr myusername mypassword mytimeout
```

Note that the option `-W 1` causes `mosquitto_sub` to timeout 1 second after connecting to the broker (so that you don't have to press `Ctrl+C` to kill the `mosquitto_sub` process).

If you have a lot of retained messages to clear, you may want to remove the `-W 1` option and kill `mosquitto_sub` manually (once it has finished publishing null messages to all topics which previously had a retained message).